# What is the equivalent of C++'s Futures in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, c++11

I was looking for an asynchronous way of setting a variable and notify the possible listeners that the variable is now available.

C++ has a great API for this use case called [std::future](https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) (`wait` and `set_value`).
But the Future's of Java are completely different...

Is there an alternative API in Java that accomplished the same behavior like in C++?

Comment: `But the Future's of Java are completely different...` How are they completely different? They are pretty much the same.

Comment: @tkausl thanks for the response, but I cannot see any `setValue()` function in the current future standard.
If I take a look in implementation I most likely need to use some kind of `FutureTask` with a `Callable` argument, and then run this inside of a `ExecutorService`

Comment: You don't need a `setValue`.  You implement something that inherits from `Callbable`.  The `call` method on your implementation of callbable returns the value to be "set".  Does that make sense?

Comment: I think you're looking for [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) ? _"A Future that may be explicitly completed (setting its value and status), and may be used as a CompletionStage, supporting dependent functions and actions that trigger upon its completion. "_

Comment: @JornVernee This was exactly what I needed, thanks :)

Comment: You obtain a `Future` from an `ExecutorService` when you submit a task (`Runnable` or `Callable`). The value is set by the result of the task. If you _really_ need to be able to explicitly set the result, then stick with `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: Well technically, I really want to avoid using the `ExecutorService` and run everything in my own thread. I don't have a problem with encapsulating my function in a `Runnable`/`Callable`, but I want to execute the function by myself, and other Threads need to wait until this work is done.

Comment: Depending on the actual structure of your code, a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) may prove useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Credit goes to @JornVernee for providing an answer in the comments*

You are looking for [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html): 

*A Future that may be explicitly completed (setting its value and status), and may be used as a CompletionStage, supporting dependent functions and actions that trigger upon its completion.*